# Android table row align to the bottom

Tags: android, alignment, tablerow

I have an aligning problem in my app. I want to create three section. 
Top side is a menu, bottom side is a menu and a map section in the middle of the screen. But as you can see in the picture, I couldn't align second menu to the bottom of the screen

Here is my layout xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context="com.ufukugur.app.MainActivity"
    android:background="#000">
<!-- menu on the top -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/ustMenu">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="7" >

            <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:id="@+id/imgLogo"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="menuHarita"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/menunokta"
                    android:id="@+id/imgMenuNokta"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imgMenuNokta"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Sembol"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="menuHarita"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/menucizgi"
                    android:id="@+id/imgMenuCizgi"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imgMenuCizgi"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Rota"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="menuHarita"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/menubolge"
                    android:id="@+id/imgMenuBolge"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imgMenuBolge"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Bölge"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="menuHarita"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/menunotam"
                    android:id="@+id/imgMenuNotam"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imgMenuNotam"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Notam"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="menuHarita"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/menufir"
                    android:id="@+id/imgMenuFir"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imgMenuFir"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="FIR"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="menuHarita"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/menutrafik"
                    android:id="@+id/imgMenuTrafik"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imgMenuTrafik"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Trafik"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>
    </RelativeLayout>

<!-- map and other things middle of the screen -->
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="GPS bağlantısı sağlanıyor..."
        android:id="@+id/textKonum"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="#ff0"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/textYakin"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="notamClicked"
        android:src="@drawable/unlems"
        android:id="@+id/imgNotam"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:id="@+id/imageGSM"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/hats_basla"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/imbKayit" />

<!-- bottom menu -->
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="6" >

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="menuHarita"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/menuharita"
                android:id="@+id/imgMenuHarita"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imgMenuHarita"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Harita"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="menuHarita"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/menuguncel"
                android:id="@+id/imgMenuGuncel"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imgMenuGuncel"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Güncelle"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="menuHarita"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/menubilgi"
                android:id="@+id/imgMenuBilgi"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imgMenuBilgi"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="HATS"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="menuHarita"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/menuayarlar"
                android:id="@+id/imgMenuAyarlar"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imgMenuAyarlar"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Ayarlar"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="menuHarita"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/menuara"
                android:id="@+id/imgMenuAra"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imgMenuAra"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Ara"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="menuHarita"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/menuradar"
                android:id="@+id/imgMenuRadar"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imgMenuRadar"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Meteo"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: insert the fragmnet and all yhr other things that has to come at the middle in a table row..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this modified layout, its entirely different from what you have created but results the same which probably you want.

```
 <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- TOP SIDE MENU AND OTHER VIEWS -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:onClick="menuHarita"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Img1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#000" />
        </LinearLayout>


         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:onClick="menuHarita"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Img2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#000" />
        </LinearLayout>

        // ADD YOUR REMAINING VIEWS HERE..........

    </LinearLayout>


    <!-- MIDDLE LAYOUT MAP AND OTHER VIEW -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/firstTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="GPS bağlantısı sağlanıyor..." 
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/firstTextView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="GPS bağlantısı sağlanıyor..." 
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

         // ADD OTHER VIEWS HERE, BE CARE FULL THE PARENT LAYOUT IS RELATIVE LAYOUT
            SO, ADD REMAINING THREE IMAGE VIEWS ACCORDINGLY......  

    </RelativeLayout>


    <!-- LOWER LAYOUT AND OTHER VIEWS VIEWING HORIZONTALLY -->

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:onClick="menuHarita"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="img1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#000" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:onClick="menuHarita"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="img2"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#000" />
        </LinearLayout>

      // ADD OTHER VIEW HERE......

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

NOTE: You need to replace my id's and other resources with yours. Just to test whether this layout
      works as per your requirement just copy and paste my layout and check. And make changes as per
      your requirement.

Comment: Thanks. It worked with a little modification. I've added tablerow for up and bottom linearlayout. Because I need to use full width screen.